# MySQL: How to merge two tables with appending distinctive and updating ambiguous rows (without PK)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How to append data from one INNODB table to another structurally identical table, but with different data and PKs:

Data from first table shoud be INSERTED into second but only if value of column `name` do not exist in second table. If it does, than i need to UPDATE specific columns of matching rows (not all). Second table is arbitrary large (~100k) rows, first is small (2k), which resulted in all my tries to fail (execution timeout) because my only thought was iterating over bigger table.

Any course of action would be helpful.

To make this more clear here is code (PHP):

```
function merge() {
  global $db;
  $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `table1`;");
  $updated = $added = 0;
  if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
      $check = $db->query("SELECT _PK FROM `table2` WHERE table2.name='".$row["name"]."';");
      if ($check->num_rows > 0) {
        $added++;
        // MY INSERT CODE GOES HERE
      } else {
        // MY UPDATE CODE GOES HERE
        $updated++;
      }
      unset($row);
    }
  }
  echo "Updated: ".$updated."<br>Added: ".$added;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it within SQL Language directly, without to use php for filtering data.
My syntax can be little different from your database version but this is the idea as you asked:

**1. Inserting rows:**

```
INSERT INTO table2 (name, other_field1, other_field2, ...)
SELECT name, other_field1, other_field2, ... FROM
(SELECT table1.name, table1.other_field1, table1.other_field2, ... 
 FROM table1
 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.name = table1.name
 WHERE table2.name IS NULL) A
```

The query explanation:

The SQL-Section in last brackets returns the rows from table1 with values of the field "name" which table2 DOES **NOT** HAVE and other fields you need. The part outside brackets inserts the selected rows into table2.

**2. Updating Rows:**

Based on the similar idea:

```
UPDATE table2 
SET other_field1 = A.other_field1,
other_field2 = A.other_field2, ...
FROM
(SELECT table1.name, table1.other_field1, table1.other_field2, ... 
     FROM table1
     LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.name = table1.name
     WHERE table2.name IS NOT NULL) A
WHERE A.name = table2.name
```

The explanation of the second query:

The SQL-Section in last brackets returns the rows from table1 with values of the field "name" which table2 DOES HAVE and other fields you need. The part outside brackets updates the corresponding rows in table2.